# Why is my NDK output library always named "libandroid-support.so"?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've assigned my library output name in my **Android.mk** file as the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_MODULE := mytest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mytest.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But the output is always `libandroid-support.so`.

Build message shows cpp files are built in to my module name `mytest`, and the output library name is still `libandroid-support.so`

```
[x86] Compile++     : mytest <= mytest.cpp
[x86] SharedLibrary : libandroid-support.so
[x86] Install       : libandroid-support.so => libs/x86/libandroid-support.so
```

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to include the `CLEAR_VARS` ndk macro to clear old ndk build state.

Issue is gone when I included the `$(CLEAR_VARS)` after the `LOCAL_PATH` assignment.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 

LOCAL_MODULE := mytest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mytest.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```